# What's the proper way to implement periodic matching system for a mySQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql, perl, scheduled-tasks, matching

Forgive me for asking if this is asked often, but I'm having trouble describing my issue and thus am having trouble finding something useful with Google.

I would like to create a "profile matching system" whereby users have two lists.  One list is a list of things they need and the other is a list of things they want.  I'd like for my website to match people based on complementary needs, but I'm not sure what the best way to go about that is.  I've built the site in Perl and I use MySQL for my database.  My first thought was that I would need a scheduled Perl script to query the DB and enter matches back into the DB to be served to users the next time they're on, but I can't think of another way to do it so I figured I'd see what the internet said.

Thanks for the help guys & gals,
Dylan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to what you want with an [SQL Join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29). Sample SQLite code:

```
.headers on
.separator "\t"
create temporary table 'buyers' (
    buyer integer primary key,
    wants char(1)
);

insert into buyers(wants) values('a');
insert into buyers(wants) values('b');
insert into buyers(wants) values('c');
insert into buyers(wants) values('d');
insert into buyers(wants) values('e');

create temporary table 'sellers' (
    seller integer primary key,
    offers char(1)
);

insert into sellers(offers) values ('a');
insert into sellers(offers) values ('b');
insert into sellers(offers) values ('b');
insert into sellers(offers) values ('e');

select
    buyers.buyer as buyer,
    sellers.seller as seller,
    buyers.wants as good
from
    buyers left outer join sellers
on
    buyers.wants = sellers.offers
;
```

Output:

```
buyer   seller  good
1       1       a
2       2       b
2       3       b
3               c
4               d
5       4       e
```

Doing something similar in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Graph::Undirected;

my $g = Graph::Undirected->new(unionfind => 1);

# buyers
$g->add_edge(b1 => 'a');
$g->add_edge(b2 => 'b');
$g->add_edge(b3 => 'c');
$g->add_edge(b4 => 'd');
$g->add_edge(b5 => 'e');

# sellers

$g->add_edge(s1 => 'a');
$g->add_edge(s2 => 'b');
$g->add_edge(s3 => 'b');
$g->add_edge(s4 => 'e');

use YAML;
print Dump [ $g->connected_components ];
```

Output:

```
-
  - a
  - b1
  - s1
-
  - s2
  - b
  - s3
  - b2
-
  - b4
  - d
-
  - e
  - b5
  - s4
-
  - b3
  - c
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the detailed answer! :)  Can you think of any other way to do it though?  Do you think this is the best way to go about creating this functionality?

Comment: I would prefer a database solution than transferring data between the Perl script and the database. I don't know enough SQL to know if what I suggested is the *best* in any way shape or form.